# Jenkins git pull overriding local changes

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins + git + SCM poll to run builds, but sometimes I have local changes on server (they happen whenever, not related to build). Whenever there are new changes in repository and build run, I lose all local changes on tracked files.

This doesn't make sense to me, is git pull not being used there? How can I make jenkins/git keep my local changes?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems jenkins does not run `git pull` to get and update. It may use `git fetch` and `git checkout` instead, which will hide your not-pushed local changes. If you want it to include your local changes, you'd better git push them once after they are made. If not, you can disable the git plugin and write `git pull` explicitly in Jenkins `Execute shell` to make sure the fetched changes will be merged with the local changes.

Comment: I have no easy way of knowing if and when local changes happen. Yeah I will probably have to use shell. Thanks for reply!